# Factor Quadratic Equation into two First Degree Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

What is the right way to break quadratic equation of following type into two first degree equations?

> Take this equation for example: $ax^2 + by^2 + cxy = d, $ where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your equation for $y$:
Dividing by $b$ gives
$$y^2-\frac{c}{b}xy+\frac{a}{b}x^2-\frac{d}{b}=0$$
solving for $y$ gives
$$y_{1,2}=-\frac{c}{2b}x\pm\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4b^2}x^2-\frac{a}{b}x^2+\frac{d}{b}}$$

Comment: Thank you. I was applying quadratic formula incorrectly and was getting irrational number as root. I saw d can be handled by bringing it to left and treating $(ax^2-d)$ as  'c' in standard equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ .

Comment: Is there any simpler way to break say $2a^2-ab-b^2=0$ into $(a-b)(2a+b)$ quickly without using quadratic formula?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly long answer to include basics. For an equation of type $ax^2 + bx+ c = 0$, roots are given by [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) $x = (-b {\pm} \sqrt{b^2-4ac} )/2a$

To solve single equation with two variables x & y, we solve for one variable and treat other variable as constant. So,
$\mathtt ax^2 + by^2 + cxy = d$ can be mapped to standard equation

$\mathtt aX^2 + \quad bX \quad + \quad c\quad\quad = 0 (_1)$ by rewriting original equation as
$\mathtt aX^2 + (cy)X + (by^2-d)\ = 0 (_2)$
where $a_1 = a_2, b_1 = cy, c_1 = by^2-d$ which gives
$X = (-b_1 {\pm} \sqrt{b_1^2-4a_1c_1} )/2a_1$
$X = (-cy {\pm} \sqrt{c^2y^2-4a(by^2-d)} )/2a$

Resolving $\pm$ gives us two roots in terms of y - root1 & root2.
The first degree factors would be (x-root1)(x-root2) = 0 as equation equals zero when x = root1 or root2.